# How can i use voice in Tizen smart TV app?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I have a project on Tizen smart TV based on React. In my project, I want to implement a voice search feature. I found [react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition), which seems like the perfect fit for my app, but when I try to import it into my app, I found my app can't use the microphone on the smart remote.

Does anyone know how to access the microphone for a Tizen app. I'm a newbie on this device. I've already imported 'http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/microphone' into privileges when building the app but nothing changes.

Comment: No answers yet?